# UITableView FooterView background color to clear color doesnt work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i try to set the UITableView Footerview backgroundcolor to clearColor but it stays white, any
other color works fine, any ideas?

```
_footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _incredientsTable.frame.size.width, 60)];
    [_footerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is your `UITableView`'s background color property set to white, by chance?

Comment: Is the tableView color white? It might be taking the tableView color. try changing the tableView color and verify.

Answer (score 3):

Ask yourself these questions:

What do you expect to see through the footer view? Is it the table's background? The underlying view controller's views? In the latter case there are more views between your and the object that you want to be visible under the footer view. That is at least the UITable itself and probably the background of self.view (which in most cases but not all is the table)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set background color of table view in this case.

```
tblView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```